# Save manipulated data with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save user details into User table but with some columns having encrypted data, But I still want to use them after decrypting into the code.
Example: User Details has username, I am encrypting and storing them in the table. But I want to use username after decrypting it.

To achieve this I added code to encrypt the username in setter of the bean and to use the value a code to decrypt the value is added in the getter, as below

```
@Table
@Entity
class User {

private String username;
private int age;

@Column
public String getUsername(){
 return Commons.decrypt(this.username);
}

@Column
public int getAge(){
 return this.age;
}

public void setUsername(String username){
 this.username = Commons.encrypt(username);
}

public void setAge(int age){}
 this.age = age;
}
```

And while saving the value in the User table, I am using `persist` method of `javax.persistence.EntityManager` class, code looks something like below

```
UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
user.setUsername("User 1");
user.setAge(31);
entityManager.persist();
```

I am expecting the code to perform as below

1. When username is set through `setter`, it should encrypt the value
2. When `persist` method is called encrypted value must be save in the DB
3. When data is fetched from database it should have encrypted username value
4. Upon calling `getter` method it should decrypt and return decrypted username

But the problem is as soon as I call the `persist` method `hibernate` internally calls `getter` and `setter` methods n number of times which finally results in saving a decrypted value i.e `User 1` instead of `eytsnkcjsdvnfsnvkscd=` in the database, Hence when I try to get data from DB a decrypted value is returned and `Commons.decrypt(this.username)` in `getter` fails.

How to achieve the above expectations through a common code strategy, I was trying in getter and setter because most of the code is already is written and is using it. Making the change in single place i.e getter and setter will automatically enable security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Spring Data, you would typically use a `Repository Interface` and do the encryption using an `AttributeConverter`.

Here's an `AttributeConverter` [example by sultanov.dev](https://sultanov.dev/blog/database-column-level-encryption-with-spring-data-jpa/):

```java
@Component
public class AttributeEncryptor implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    private static final String AES = "AES";
    private static final String SECRET = "secret-key-12345";

    private final Key key;
    private final Cipher cipher;

    public AttributeEncryptor() throws Exception {
        key = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET.getBytes(), AES);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(attribute.getBytes()));
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData)));
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The entity `User` would then only contain the fundamental data fields and getter/setter methods (Lombok for brevity) and a `@Convert` annotation for the username.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Convert(converter = AttributeEncryptor.class)
    private String username;

    private int age;
}
```

The `@Column` annotation is used when an attribute in the entity is drawn from the secondary table, with a table attribute identifying the appropriate table. I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve marking the getter methods as columns.

Access to stored objects is commonly achieved using one of Sping Data's Repository Interfaces, e.g. `JpaRepository`.

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    
}
```

In your Service Layer, you should then be able to work with data from repository with encryption being handled automatically.

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User loadUser(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);;   
    }

    @Transactional  
    public User save(User user) {
        return repository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works well, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is due to the way Hibernate interacts with entity getters and setters during the persisting and retrieving process. Hibernate uses getters and setters to access entity properties, which in your case leads to unintentional decryption and re-encryption.

To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

1. **Separate Database and Domain Model**: Instead of directly encrypting and decrypting in the getter and setter of the `User` entity, you can introduce a separate domain model class. This class will represent the decrypted version of your data for use in the application logic.
2. **Utilize @PrePersist and @PostLoad Annotations**: Use these annotations to handle encryption and decryption outside of the getters and setters. This ensures that the data is encrypted before being persisted and decrypted after being loaded from the database, without interfering with the standard getter/setter behavior.
3. **Refactor Your Entity Class**:

   - Keep the `username` as a plain string in the `User` entity.
   - Use `@PrePersist` to encrypt the username just before persisting.
   - Use `@PostLoad` to decrypt the username right after loading it from the database.

Here's how you can refactor your `User` entity:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table
class User {

    @Column
    private String username;
    private int age;

    // Standard getters and setters
    public String getUsername(){
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    @PrePersist
    private void encryptFields() {
        this.username = Commons.encrypt(this.username);
    }

    @PostLoad
    private void decryptFields() {
        this.username = Commons.decrypt(this.username);
    }
}
```

In this approach:

- The `@PrePersist` method `encryptFields` is called before the entity manager persists the entity, ensuring that the `username` is encrypted in the database.
- The `@PostLoad` method `decryptFields` is called after the entity is loaded from the database, decrypting the `username` for use in your application.

This way, the standard getters and setters remain unaffected, and encryption/decryption is handled transparently during the persistence and retrieval phases. This strategy should meet your requirement of encrypting data for storage while still being able to use decrypted data in your code.

Comment: Annotations were working very well with my use case but the only problem is when there is refresh fired and after @postload execution there is an additional update being fired as the data is manipulated